# Why does the classical path give the dominant contribution in the path integral?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, path-integral, semiclassical, asymptotics

Why is it that the classical path gives the dominant contribution in the quantum mechanical path integral? How do we understand this?

Comment: possible duplicates: [Classical Limit of the Feynman Path Integral](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32237), [Classical limit of quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32112).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56151/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 7):

In the classical limit $\hbar\to 0$, this is just the [WKB/stationary phase approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation).

1. Heuristically, near a stationary field configuration $\phi_0$ with
   $$\left. \frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta\phi}\right|_{\phi_0}~=~0\tag{1}$$
   in field configuration space, the action
   $$S[\phi]~=~S[\phi_0]+{\cal O}\left((\phi-\phi_0)^2\right)\tag{2}$$
   varies slowly, so the phase factors
   $\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi]\right)$
   from neighboring field configurations sum up, and give a contribution; while away from a stationary field configuration $\phi_0$, the action varies rapidly, and the phases of neighboring field configurations are uncorrelated and cancel in average.
2. Perturbatively, near each stationary field configuration $\phi_0$, let us parametrize the field
   $$\phi^k~=~\phi^k_0+\sqrt{\hbar}\eta^k\tag{3}$$
   in terms of a quantum fluctuation field $\eta^k$. Then the argument of the exponential reads$^1$
   $$\begin{align}\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi]~=~&\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi_0] 
   ~+~ \frac{i}{2}H_{k\ell}[\phi_0]~\eta^k\eta^{\ell} \cr
   &~+~ {\cal O}(\sqrt{\hbar}),\end{align}\tag{4} $$
   where
   $$ H_{k\ell}[\phi]~:=~  \frac{\delta^2 S[\phi]}{\delta\phi^k\delta\phi^{\ell}}\tag{5}$$
   is the [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix).
   The path/functional integral
   $$\begin{align}Z~=~~&\int\!{\cal D}\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{\hbar}}~\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi]\right) \cr  
   \stackrel{(3)+(4)}{=}&\sum_{\phi_0}\int\!{\cal D}\eta~\cr
   &\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi_0]+\frac{i}{2}H_{k\ell}[\phi_0]~\eta^k\eta^{\ell} + {\cal O}(\sqrt{\hbar})\right)\cr
   \stackrel{\text{WKB}}{\sim}~&\sum_{\phi_0}{\rm Det}\left(\frac{1}{i} H_{k\ell}[\phi_0]\right)^{-1/2}~\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi_0]\right)\cr
   &\quad\text{for}\quad\hbar~\to~0\end{align}\tag{6} $$
   becomes formally a sum over [instantons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instanton) $\phi_0$, i.e. classical field configurations.
3. For a simple introduction into this topic with many pictures and almost no formulas, see e.g. [this blog post](http://www.thephysicsmill.com/2013/07/16/reality-is-the-feynman-path-integral/) by The Physics Mill.

--

$^1$Here we are using [DeWitt condensed notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeWitt_notation).

Comment: Notes for later: Action: $S[\phi] +J_k\phi^k$ $=\frac{\hbar}{2}\eta^kH_{k\ell}[\phi_0]\eta^{\ell} +S_{\neq 2}[\phi_0,\sqrt{\hbar}\eta]+J_k\phi^k$ $=\frac{\hbar}{2}\eta^kH_{k\ell}[\phi_0]\eta^{\ell} +S_{\neq 2}[\phi_0, \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta J_k}] +J_k\phi^k,$ where EOM $\left.\frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta \phi^k}\right|_{\phi=\phi_0}=0$ and $\phi_0$ are defined WITHOUT sources. Hm. Not a stationary point for $J\neq 0$, so WKB does not apply. NB: It is a bit delicate what $J$-dependence should be differentiated.

Comment: Action with only fluctuation source: $\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi] +j_k\eta^k$ $=\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi_0+\sqrt{\hbar}\eta] +j_k\eta^k$ $=\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi_0] 
+\frac{i}{2}H_{k\ell}[\phi_0]\eta^k\eta^{\ell} +\frac{i}{\hbar}S_{\rm int}[\phi_0,\sqrt{\hbar}\eta] +j_k\eta^k$ $=\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi_0] 
+\frac{i}{2}H_{k\ell}[\phi_0]\eta^k\eta^{\ell} +\frac{i}{\hbar}S_{\rm int}[\phi_0,\sqrt{\hbar}\frac{\delta}{\delta j}] +j_k\eta^k.$ Source term is suppressed with $\hbar$ so it doesn't change the stationary point $\phi_0$. Propagator $\exp\left(\frac{i}{2}(H^{-1})^{k\ell}[\phi_0]j_kj_{\ell} \right).$

Comment: It is possible to calculate quantum corrections perturbatively in $\hbar$. For a single variable $\eta$ in 0D, one can use the formula $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!d\eta ~\eta^n e^{-\frac{a}{2}\eta^2}~=~\left(\frac{2}{a}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})~=~(n-1)!!\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a^{n+1}}}$ if $n$ even (and 0 if $n$ odd).

Answer (score 0):

The contribution of paths deviating from the classical path are suppressed by interference.