# Confusions on expectation value for $\hbar$ going to zero

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, symmetry-breaking, semiclassical, asymptotics

In Matthew D. Schwartz's QFT book, Chapter 28, the author claims when $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, the following equality (eq 28.4) holds:

[image]

So how can I see the second "$=$" holds? It seems the method of stationary phase is inapplicable?

UPDATE:
Below are my calculations:
By definition,
\begin{equation}
\langle \Omega|\phi(x)|\Omega \rangle=\frac{\int \mathcal{D}\phi \exp\{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi]\}\phi(x)}{\int \mathcal{D}\phi \exp\{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi]\}}.
\end{equation}
Suppose the solution of equation of motion $\delta S=0$ is given by $\phi=v=$ constant. We write $\phi=\eta+v$ and the expectation value is now
\begin{equation}
\langle \Omega|\phi(x)|\Omega \rangle=v+\frac{\int \mathcal{D}\eta \exp\{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\eta+v]\}\eta(x)}{\int \mathcal{D}\eta \exp\{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\eta+v]\}}.
\end{equation}
We continue to deal with $S$ up to 2nd order:
\begin{equation}
S[\eta+v]=S[v]+\mbox{vanishing linear term}+\frac{1}{2}S''[v]\eta^2.
\end{equation}
After some functional algebra, we get something like
\begin{equation}
\frac{\int \mathcal{D}\eta \exp\{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\eta+v]\}\eta(x)}{\int \mathcal{D}\eta \exp\{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\eta+v]\}}=(-i\hbar)\frac{\partial}{\partial J(x)}\exp\{\int dx' dy\frac{i}{\hbar}J(x')[-2S''(v)]^{-1}J(y)\}|_{J=0}.
\end{equation}
So the righthand side is vanishing under limit $\hbar \rightarrow 0$?
I am not sure whether or not my calculation is correct.

Comment: In what sense do you think the method of stationary phase is inapplicable?

Comment: @J.Murray I think beacuse a $\phi(x)$ is inserted into the path integral?

Comment: If you can articulate why you think that is problematic, you may have better luck finding an answer.

Comment: @J.Murray I have updated some calculations. Could you have a look?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Scale the quantum fluctuations $\eta$ with a factor $\sqrt{\hbar}$, i.e. put $$\phi~=~v+\sqrt{\hbar}\eta.$$ This makes it easier to see that the extra terms vanish as $\hbar\to 0$. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/351072/2451) related Phys.SE post.