# On the computation of functionals in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, semiclassical, locality

Using the Gaussian (path)-integral

$$
\int \mathcal{D}\eta e^{i\int_{t_i}^{t_f} dt \eta(t) O(t) \eta(t)} = N [\operatorname{det} O(t)]^{-1/2}
$$

my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9812568476) claims that we can compute the following integral as

$$
N e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[x_{cl}]}\int \mathcal{D} \eta \exp\left(\frac{i}{2\hbar} \int \int dt_1 dt_2 \eta(t_1)\frac{\delta^2 S[x_{cl}]}{\delta x_{cl}(t_1) \delta x_{cl}(t_2)}\eta(t_2)\right)
=\frac{N}{\sqrt{\operatorname{det}\Big(\frac{1}{\hbar} \frac{\delta^2 S[x_{cl}]}{\delta x_{cl}(t_1) \delta x_{cl}(t_2)}}\Big)}e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[x_{cl}]}\tag{7.35}
$$

using the above identity. What happened with one integration over $t_2$ in applying the formula? Why is this valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For a local action functional $S[x]$ the Hessian $ \frac{\delta^2 S[x]}{\delta x(t_1) \delta x(t_2)}$ is proportional to a Dirac delta distribution $\delta(t_1\!-\!t_2)$. See e.g. eq. (7.37) in Ref. 1.

See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/351072/2451) related Phys.SE post.

References:

1. A. Das, *Field Theory: A Path Integral Approach;*  eq. (7.35).