# Help to evaluate an integral given in appendix of Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, semiclassical, asymptotics

On p. 16 in appendix 3 in section I.2 of *Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell* by Zee the integral to be evaluated is  $$I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dqe^{-(1/\hbar)f(q)}.$$

Where $f(q)$ is expanded as

$$f(q) =f(a)+\frac{1}{2}f’’(a)(q-a)^{2}+O[(q-a)^{3}].$$

Then the resultant is

$$I = e^{-(1/\hbar)f(a)}(\frac{2\pi\hbar}{f’’(a)})^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-O(\hbar^{\frac{1}{2}})}.\tag{27}$$

Where does the term $\hbar^{\frac{1}{2}} $ in the power of exponential in the resultant comes from?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/351072/2451