# Multiple saddles in path integral

Tags: gravity, path-integral, quantum-gravity, semiclassical, instantons

I am reading the [Jerusalem Lectures by Harlow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1231). On page 44 he calculates the thermal partition function using the path integral with no matter fields,
$$
Z(\beta) = \int \mathcal{D}[g] e^{-I_E[g]}.
$$
The calculation is done using saddle-point techniques
$$
Z(\beta) \approx \sum_{g_\text{cl}} e^{-I_E[g_\text{cl}]},
$$
where $g_\text{cl}$ are classical solutions of the Einstein equations. I am confused by this sum as I have not seen a similar case in which one expands around *multiple* saddles in ordinary QFT.

I have read several articles where the approximation is taken around a single saddle $g_\text{cl}$. This is achieved by writing $g = g_\text{cl} + \delta g$ and expanding the action as
$$
I_E[g] = I_E[g_\text{cl}] + I_{E,2}[\delta g] + \dots
$$
to obtain
$$
\log Z = -I_E[g_\text{cl}] + \log\int \mathcal{D}[\delta g] e^{-I_{E,2}[\delta g]} + \dots
$$
If we include only the first term, we get
$$
Z(\beta) \approx e^{-I_E[g_{cl}]},
$$
which agrees with the sum formula for one saddle. How can we show that the sum formula holds for multiple saddles?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ref. 1 uses the [method of steepest descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent) with multiple stationary/saddle points/[instanton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instanton) sectors in the semiclassical limit $\hbar\to 0$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/351072/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. More precisely, the presence xor absence of each saddle point in the sum may depend on the integration contour. See e.g. my Math.SE answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1963893/11127) for how this works in practice for an Airy function toy model.

References:

1. D. Harlow, *Jerusalem Lectures on Black Holes and Quantum Information,* [arXiv:1409.1231](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1231).